# Are html5 streamed videos cacheable?

Tags: http, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm using jwplayer to play videos in html5 mode.
Videos are in mp4 format.

What I'm seeing in the network tab are bunch of network requests with 206 status (partial download). So my understanding is -> video is just being streamed in partial chunks, 1-2 Mb each.

But can those chunks be cached in the browser?
Currently I'm seeing video just being re-streamed every time...

Answer (score 2):

With reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37217951/3012385): Yes, 206 responses are cacheable. This is also explicitly stated in [RFC 7233, section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-4.1):

> A 206 response is cacheable by default; i.e., unless otherwise indicated by explicit cache controls

This does not mean that browser *do* cache those, of course. But they certainly can.

Comment: hmm. thanks. why in the word then it's not caching?   https://paste.fedoraproject.org/368105/14635949/   Seems like all of the proper headers are set.

Comment: Perhaps the browser vendor decided it's not worth it? Streaming is supposed to be an ad-hoc thing anyway.

Comment: browser is google chrome. it caches when jwplayer is in flash mode.

Comment: im not sure if that still the case. I can see 304 responses with console out. As long as "Disable cache" is unchecked.

Comment: @Dannyboy That's interesting to say the least. That response has all the right headers set to be considered cacheable by any means. Perhaps it's "too much" for Chrome? I really don't know ...